# java.util.MissingResourceException

Tags: java, resourcebundle

I am getting below exception while running an application. This application read abc.properties file,

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name abc, locale en_US
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(ResourceBundle.java:853)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:822)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:566)
    at com.ibm.dst.DailyExtract.getResourceBundle(DailyExtract.java:104)
    at com.ibm.dst.DailyExtract.main(DailyExtract.java:131)
```

abc.properties file reside at the workspace.
I am using RSA7 as IDE, is there any setting problem?
any suggestions are welcome.....

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Can you confirm whether the file is in your classpath at runtime?  Perhaps provide the code and file layout you're using.

Answer (score 13):

Follow the hints in [this post](https://blogs.oracle.com/chengfang/entry/p_java_util_missingresourceexception_can) and see if you made one of those mistakes, which could be (copy pasted from the link):

1. These resource properties files are loaded by classloader, similar to java classes.  So you need to include them in your runtime classpath.
2. These resources have fully-qualified-resource-name, similar to a fully-qualified-class-name, excerpt you can't import a resource into your java source file.  Why? because its name takes the form of a string.
3. `ResourceBundle.getBundle("config")` tells the classloader to load a resource named "config" with default package (that is, no package).  It does NOT mean a resource in the current package that has the referencing class.
4. `ResourceBundle.getBundle("com.cheng.scrap.config")` tells the classloader to load a resource named "config" with package "com.cheng.scrap."  Its fully-qualified-resource-name is "com.cheng.scrap.config"

Comment: I had the same error, my properties files were located in the same package as the class file, specifying the fully qualified name (package name + properties file name) worked with me

Answer (score 4):

You just need to add the package name while getting the file

For example if your properties name is "ABC.properties" in package a.b.c then the below code will work perfectly

```
ResourceBundle labels = ResourceBundle.getBundle("a.b.c.ABC");
```

Answer (score 2):

Just copy the resource file over to where your class files are.

In my case my directory was:

```
bin 
  - com 
     - brookf 
        - all my packages here.
```

copy your resource file to the bin folder.

Answer (score 1):

Loading the Properties file for localization stuff is also affected by the package naming. If you put your Properties file in a package like `org.example.com.foobar` and load it just by its name `abc` you have to add the prefix `org.example.com.foobar`, too. If you have the properties at a different location (like in the root directory or in another subdir) you have to change either the name to load or the classpath.

I run fine in placing the properties file in the same location where the `.java` file is and using something like

```
private static ResourceBundle RES = ResourceBundle.getBundle(NameOfTheCurrentClass.class.getCanonicalName());
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue today and it took me a while until I figured out a fix (I'm using Eclipse as an IDE). My project folder contains the *.properties-Files in the following path:

```
project/src/strings
```

Since strings is a sub-folder of src and src is already in the build path of the project (see Property Window), all I needed was to add an Inclusion-Pattern for the *.properties-Files:

```
**/*.properties
```

There should be already an Inclusion-Pattern for *.java-Files (**/*.java)

Maybe there is something similar for your IDE

Answer (score 0):

Is the file in your classpath? If it is, try renaming it to abc_en_US.properties