# how to modify the maven jar-plugin to fix the MissingResourceException error

Tags: java, maven, jar

I'm really bad at maven and I get that MissingResourceException error:

[image: error in cmd after java -jar myJarFile.jar]

So and here is my pom.xml (build):

```
    <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                     <manifest>
                          <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                          <addDefaultSpecificationEntries>true</addDefaultSpecificationEntries>           
                          <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                          <mainClass>org.jis.Main</mainClass>
                     </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.14</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.puppycrawl.tools</groupId>
                    <artifactId>checkstyle</artifactId>
                    <version>6.4.1</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <configuration>
                <consoleOutput>true</consoleOutput>
                <configLocation>${basedir}/src/test/resources/checkstyle_swt1.xml</configLocation>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <descriptor>src/assembly/src.xml</descriptor>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

my src.xml:

```
<assembly
xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.2.xsd">
<id>src</id>
<includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
<formats>
    <format>zip</format>
</formats>

    <files>
            <file>
                    <source>.gitignore</source>
                    <destName>gitignore.txt</destName>
            </file>
    </files>
<fileSets>
    <fileSet>
            <outputDirectory/>
            <includes>
                <include>${project.basedir}/src/main/java/org/jis/generator/Consumer.java</include>
                <include>${project.basedir}/src/main/java/org/jis/generator/Element.java</include>
                <include>${project.basedir}/src/main/java/org/jis/generator/Generator.java</include>
                <include>${project.basedir}/src/main/java/org/jis/generator/LayoutGalerie.java</include>
                <include>${project.basedir}/src/main/java/org/jis/generator/Producer.java</include>
                <include>${project.basedir}/src/main/java/org/jis/generator/TableGalerie.java</include>
                <include>${project.basedir}/src/main/java/org/jis/listner/CloseListner.java</include>
                <include>${project.basedir}/src/main/java/org/jis/listner/ExitListner.java</include>
                <include>${project.basedir}/src/main/java/org/jis/listner/MenuListner.java</include>
                <include>${project.basedir}/src/main/java/org/jis/options/Options.java</include>
                <include>${project.basedir}/src/main/java/org/jis/view/dialog/AboutBox.java</include>
                <include>${project.basedir}/src/main/java/org/jis/view/dialog/GallerieDialog.java</include>
                <include>${project.basedir}/src/main/java/org/jis/view/dialog/Layout.java</include>
                <include>${project.basedir}/src/main/java/org/jis/view/dialog/OptionsEdit.java</include>
                <include>${project.basedir}/src/main/java/org/jis/view/FileTree.java</include>
                <include>${project.basedir}/src/main/java/org/jis/view/List.java</include>
                <include>${project.basedir}/src/main/java/org/jis/view/Menu.java</include>
                <include>${project.basedir}/src/main/java/org/jis/view/Preview.java</include>
                <include>${project.basedir}/src/main/java/org/jis/view/Status.java</include>
                <include>${project.basedir}/src/main/java/org/jis/view/Thumbnail.java</include>
                <include>${project.basedir}/src/main/java/org/jis/view/Toolbar.java</include>
                <include>${project.basedir}/src/main/java/org/jis/Main.java</include>
                <include>${project.basedir}/src/main/java/org/jis/Messages.java</include>
            </includes>
        </fileSet>

    <fileSet>
        <directory>target</directory>
        <includes>       
            <include>pom.xml</include>
        </includes>
    </fileSet>


    <fileSet>
        <directory>target</directory>
        <includes>
            <include>changelog.xml</include>
            <include>changelog.html</include>
       </includes>
       <outputDirectory>docs</outputDirectory>
   </fileSet>


    </fileSets>
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here but I read at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2636572/3906077) that it could happen because my properties and class files are at the same place in my jar file.

[image: my jar file]

[image: my folder structure]

but how do I fix this in my pom.xml?

Edit:

The error message as text

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle
 for base name org.jis.messages, locale en
      at java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(Unknown       Source
 )
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(Unknown Source)
    at org.jis.Messages.<init>(Messages.java:42)
    at org.jis.Main.<init>(Main.java:86)
    at org.jis.Main.main(Main.java:201)
```

Comment: Can you please copy/paste the full text of the Maven error message, instead of a screen shot? Thanks!!

Comment: editted it into the main question