# How do I use inner classes with ListResourceBundle?

Tags: java

Inside a class BankTeller, I have 3 inner classes that extend ListResourceBundle, namely,

- BankTeller_ja_JP
- BankTeller_el_GR
- BankTeller_en_GB

Inside a main method for BankTeller, I want to use these classes. I tried using

```
ResourceBundle res = ResourceBundle.getBundle("BankTeller$BankTeller",locale);
ResourceBundle res = ResourceBundle.getBundle("BankTeller.BankTeller",locale);
```

But both gave me the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name BankTeller$BankTeller, locale el_GR
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(Unknown Source)
    at lab10.BankTeller.displayValues(BankTeller.java:16)
    at lab10.BankTeller.main(BankTeller.java:12)
```

How do I load the ResourceBundles?

Comment: I am pretty sure that the locale classes should not be inner classes.

Comment: Nevermind, this may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2636521/java-util-missingresourceexception It looks like your resources are probably in the wrong location.

Comment: Ummm @sorifiend they are in the right location. Just that my inner classes are giving trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If You want to use nested class, Your BankTeller should be **public static** nested class.
I have created class ResourceBundleTest in package com.java.util:

```java
class ResourceBundleTest {

    @Test
    void getBundle_fromNestedStaticClass() {
        // given
        final Locale locale = new Locale("en", "GB");
        // when
        final ResourceBundle exampleBundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("com.java.util.ResourceBundleTest$BankTeller", locale);
        // then
        assertEquals("Hello World!", exampleBundle.getString("greetings"));
    }

    public static class BankTeller_en_GB extends ListResourceBundle {

        @Override
        protected Object[][] getContents() {
            return new Object[][]{{"greetings", "Hello World!"}};
        }

    }
}
```